# Incorrect drawing diagrams in plotly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot, plotly

I have selected some data in DB. And draw diagrams in plotly.

```
df1.DataFrame().head()

    job_name          job_start_date  min_difference
0   VSK_NIGHT_3HOUR     2019-11-19    2542
1   VSK_NIGHT_1HOUR     2019-11-27    156
2   VSK_NIGHT_24HOUR    2019-11-27    240
3   VSK_NIGHT_1HOUR     2019-11-29    205
4   VSK_NIGHT_5HOUR     2019-12-11    66
```

```
df1.DataFrame().iplot(
    x='job_start_date',
    y='min_difference',
    mode='lines+markers',
    symbol='square',
    size=5,
    categories='job_name',)
```

After i take 
[broken diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Jkr.png). When
really it should look like this
[correct diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU0tS.png)

What problem could it be?

Comment: `sort` before you plot: `df1 = df1.sort_values('job_start_date')`